# How to integrate $\frac{1}{x\sqrt{x}}$

Tags: integration

How to integrate $$\frac{1}{x\sqrt{x}}$$ I don't see how could I use u substitution or integration by parts. I tried both, but it just got worse(more complex). I haven't integrate in years and I just can't warp my head around this.

**Edit**:
Thank you everybody who helped me. It was really simple and obvious. Now it is easy.

Comment: $1/(x\sqrt x)=x^{-3/2}$.

Comment: Rewrite it as $x^{-3/2}$. Then use the power rule.

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to format mathematics on this site.

Comment: Which one should I accept as an answer? I guess the first in chronological order.

Comment: Suppose that you wanted to use a substitution (not the easiest way, but for academic interest...).  A substitution like $u^2=x, 2u\text du = \text dx$ is one way, but maybe more interesting would be $v=\frac 1{\sqrt x},\text dv=-\frac{\text dx}{2x\sqrt x}$:  $$\int{1\over x\sqrt x}\text dx=-2\int \text dv=-2v+C=-\frac 2{\sqrt x}+C$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\int\frac{dx}{x\sqrt x}=\int\frac{dx}{x^{3/2}}=\int x^{-3/2}dx=\color{red}{-\frac{2}{\sqrt x}+\mathcal C}$$

Answer (score 4):

Hint:
$$
\frac{1}{x\sqrt{x}}=\frac{1}{x^{3/2}}=x^{-3/2}
$$

now can you find a primitive?

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $1/(x\sqrt x) = x^{-3/2}$ so its primitive is $-2x^{-1/2}$.

Comment: That is more than a hint.

Answer (score 1):

Notice, when $n>1$:

$$\int\frac{1}{x^n}\space\text{d}x=\int x^{-n}\space\text{d}x=\frac{x^{1-n}}{1-n}+\text{C}$$

Comment: Yes. I've used this. Thanks. I just overlooked the fact that I can move x inside the √ as x²

Comment: @SzőkeSzabolcs You're welcome!

Comment: Should be OK over any interval with $x > 0$, but the final expression won't be valid if $n=1$.

Comment: @Bungo Yes that's true, thats why I choose to put in $n>1$ because the antiderivative of $\frac{1}{x}$ is $\ln|x|+\text{C}$